# Restoring Navicat backup files

Tags: restore, database-restore, navicat

I have made the backup from Navicat files in following formats:

*.backup
*.nppb
*.ncx

How can I restore the tables?

Answer (score 1):

- Create new DB
- Open it
- Then `backup` (see image)

[image]

- So you can pick up your tables (copy them to desired DB)

Comment: Thank youuu!! This work's for me

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a screenshot, right click and select that option

**In english is called restore backup from...**

[image: Restore database PSC]

Answer (score 0):

If you created the backup under public/backups, This should work.

```
a. navigate to the DC/public and click the Backups button 
b. Click the + add button 
c. Under the Advanced tab to name the backup click user specified file checkbox name and write name
d. Then hit play looking button “Start”
e. Now this will show up in Backups
f. To Restore backup click the backup you want then the open button with folder picture.     
Then hit start and everything will be reloaded.
Note: For some reason, to see data changes, you must right click in each to table to have them reload correctly.
```